# How to set subscribe the plan in android using stripe payment?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am implementing the stripe payment gateway in my android app. Up to Now I am able to validate the credit card using stripe but I got stuck to subscribe . I am unable to set `Stripe.api_key` in app. Its shows cannot resolve variable. If I remove `Stripe.api_key` then app throw following exception

> `Stripe::AuthenticationError - No API key provided.  (HINT: set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>".  You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface.  See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.):`

please help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

The only part of the payment flow that should be done directly within a native Android app is the collection and tokenization of the customer's payment information, using [Stripe's Android SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android).

Once the token has been created, you must sent it to a backend server, where you can use it to [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer), then use the customer to [create a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription).

The reason you can't do this directly from the app is because those requests require that you use your secret API key, and the secret API key should never in any way be shared or embedded with the app. Otherwise, an attacker could retrieve it and use it to access your account and issue API requests on your behalf.