# How to update saved credit card information using stripe from app side(swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, stripe-payments

I have issue regarding Stripe.I am using Stripe for payment in my app.So is it possible that i can update stored user's card information from app side ? is there any method for update stored card information from application side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, this is not possible.

Cf. [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40375005/5307473) (I talked about Android in that answer but iOS is in the same boat).